Custom ESP32-S3 PCB not connecting to PC
I am new to electronics and PCB design and am trying to make a little sensor hub thing based on the ESP32-S3 using the SeeedStudio XIAO Round Display via pin headers.
I have designed the following schematic and PCB:



(the weird cutouts have to do with the housing I made for the device)
I had the PCB manufactured and assembled it myself, reflow soldering the components onto the board using a hot plate. The missing resistor on the left below the USB-C connector is a pullup for USB D+ that I had in the schematic initially, but since the SeeedStudio XIAO ESP32S3 doesn't have it either, I left it out here. I checked for shorts where I could, but since the ESP is covering its pins, I could only check the pin headers and the ports of the USB-C connector.
Note that I didn't add any of the sensors, i.e. only the ESP, the USB-C connector, the buttons, and resistors/capacitors are on the board. Also, note that the PCB does not work on its own, as it cannot convert VBUS to 3V3. This function is handled by the SeeedStudio display's PCB, which I have verified to be working.
When connecting the board to the display and plugging it into my computer, the display lights up (i.e. it has power), however no new USB device is recognized by the computer. I held the BOOT button while plugging it in, which should get the ESP into USB Download Mode and should make it at least appear on the computer.
Measuring voltages, I could see that I am getting ~5V via USB, and the 3V3 pin from the display is on a stable +3V3 compared to GND. The EN and IO0 pins of the ESP are at 3V3 (when not pressing the buttons) as well.
This is my first PCB and I don't know where to look to find the issue that is stopping my computer from recognizing the board as a USB device. Does anyone have some pointers to further investigate? Thank you for your help!

Note: I used the SeeedStudio XIAO ESP32S3 design as a reference for wiring the USB connector:

I would start by making sure that R8 and R9 didn't get fried during the PCB soldering process, and would confirm that you're getting a connection from your MCU data pins to the USB data pins. Since you're hand soldering, double checking your solder job is important since it's a variable in troubleshooting.

Thank you for your response! I checked R8 and R9 and they are intact. I don't know how I'm supposed to check the data connection to the MCU, since it is covering the pins. There is a connection through the resistors and to the USB data pins though.

"I don't know how I'm supposed to check the data connection to the MCU, since it is covering the pins": make a note to yourself for your future pcbs: make sure I have test points I can reach.  I don't see any pin1 marks ... are you certain the chip is on the right way around?  Power traces look very thin: are they enough.

Yes, have already made that note haha. For the ESP, I've used the shape of the middle ground pads for alignment and I'm certain it is the right way around. Adding a more visible indicator is still a good idea though. About the power traces: I'm measuring the correct voltage everywhere and power lines are connected; not sure how else to check that...
